# Is it possiable to limit importhtml in Google sheet?

Tags: if-statement, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have lot of data on Google sheet. I run importhtml formula to get data. as I have a lot of data I got error

```
Error
Loading data may take a while because of the large number of requests. Try to reduce the amount of IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED or IMPORTXML functions across spreadsheets that you've created.
```

So I just want to run formula only when first get the result then next cell run import formula . for ex:

in this sheet all formulas run on the same time, is there any way when a1 formula got values than cell A2 run, and when Cell a2 got values then Cell A3 run

```
       |      Column A |              
  =====| =================================
   A1  | =query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(H2, "table", 1)), "select * limit 1 offset 1", 0)  
  =====| =================================
   A2  | =query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(H2, "table", 1)), "select * limit 1 offset 1", 0)  
  =====| =================================
   A3  | =query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(H2, "table", 1)), "select * limit 1 offset 1", 0)
```

and want like something this

```
       |      Column A |              
  =====| =================================
   A1  | =query(TRANSPOSE(ImportHtml(H2, "table", 1)), "select * limit 1 offset 1", 0)  
  =====| =================================
   A2  | wait for get result for A1  


       |      Column A |              
  =====| =================================
   A1  | Name 1  
  =====| =================================
   A2  | A1 get result now run formula here
```

Hope it makes some sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to build on the error you got and wrap your formula into `IF` statement like:

A1: `your formula`
A2: `=IF(ISERROR(A1),,your formula)`
A3: `=IF(ISERROR(A2),,your formula)`
etc.